# Harry Potter fanfiction with Draco as a florist

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

I read this a little while ago, long enough to forget what it’s called, but it was a story where Draco works in a flower shop and had run away from Malfoy manor after getting the Dark Mark. Hermione, Harry and Ron come crashing into the shop he works at, running away from Fenrir Greyback, and he takes them to his house, that he warded away from everyone that could possibly find it, as far away from the magical world as he could.

I remember he had this room that he stayed in to paint and he locked it and one night Harry snuck in with his cloak. I also remember that Harry and Draco got together and Draco’s house got destroyed, which got him upset because it was Harry’s fault for letting Lord Voldemort into his head while he was sleeping with Draco.

Comment: Do you remember what site it was on?

Comment: I know that it was either Wattpad AO3 or FanFiction.net so not much help. I’m pretty sure it was either Wattpad or FanFiction because it was a little before I started really getting into AO3 and I’m feeling closer to Wattpad because it was before I reached the weird FanFictions but it could be any of the three because they’re all I use