# Drarry Fanfiction, w Draco at a flower shop

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

So I remember the fic was on a03 and Draco ran away after the war. He owns a flower shop but he has this evil entity on his head?? And then Harry walks in the shop and is surprised by Draco. He meets up at his house for dinner but Draco keeps punishing himself because "he's not allowed." TO do that. So he would like kneel on glass for a while.

Comment: Do you recognize any of the details from [Harry Potter fanfiction with Draco as a florist](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/188529/82909)? Or do you think that's a different story?

Comment: No that's not it

Answer (score 2):

It's [*Some Flowers Bloom in the Dark*](https://archiveofourown.org/works/28174179/chapters/69036978).

Comment: Care to tell us a bit about it?  Link-only answers are discouraged because they can become useless if the link vanishes.